# How to append different text to multiple elements?

Tags: javascript

I have an existing form and and need to attach tooltip text to each form field label - There are about 20 form fields, and each one has a different tool tips.

My current method is to create a variable for each label, and a variable for each tooltip, and then use appendChild to add each tool tip to the correct label.

Is there a better way of approaching this?

Thanks!

Current method:

```
var labelOne = document.getElementById( 'label_1' ),
tipTextOne = document.createTextNode( 'Lorem impus dolor sit amet' ),
tipElOne = document.createElement( 'span' );

tipElOne.appendChild( tipTextOne );
labelOne.appendChild( tipElOne );
```

etc...

Comment: Store the Tool tips in an array. Then, loop over the elements and assign the tool tip corresponding to the current element to that element. You won't use `.appendChild` though because a tool tip is created by setting the `title` attribute, so you can just set the `title` property of each element.

Comment: This: _Is there a better way of approaching this?_ - Yes, statically place them into the DOM elements.

Comment: You can create an `object` that maps each label `id` to his tooltip text. After this, you can use a loop to assign each tooltip to the corresponding label. Could you add a minimum markup with `3` or `4` labels and what you expect to get?

Comment: Please provide us with an objective definition of "better".

Comment: Apologies for the confusion, I'm not talking about using the title attribute, but a span element that can be manipulated with css, so that the design can be implemented correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Use a map of element id -> child element text. Then, iterate through the keys of the map, adding tooltips to each element by updating their `title` attribute. This will allow you to reduce repetition in your code:

```
let map = {};
map.label_1 = 'Lorem impus dolor sit amet';
map.label_2 = 'abcd';
// etc

Object.keys(map).forEach(key => {
  document.getElementById( key ).setAttribute('title', map[key]);
});
```

Technically it's an object not a [Map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map), but for 20 elements, using an object is cleaner.

Comment: Using `id`s creates a brittle solution and more code bloat than needed.

Answer (score -1):

You could just use the `title` prop of each element if you don't need a fancy tooltip and rely on the browser given one that shows on hover of elements with titles.

```html
<div title="foo">Example text!</div>
```

Comment: This doesn't address the actual question.